Problem with LCEL lanchais RAG sequential chains
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to connect chains in my LCEL-langchain-Python code. Specifically, I'm receiving an error message that says 'expected string or buffer'. I've thoroughly tested all relevant variables, and they all belong to the str class.
Interestingly, when I run the code without linking the chains individually, everything works as expected. However, when I attempt to connect the chains, this error arises.
I've tried troubleshooting by checking the data types of the variables involved, ensuring they are all strings, but the error persists.
Could someone please provide insights into why I might be encountering this error when attempting to connect the chains? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
That's my code; I'm trying to implement a chatbot using lanchais chains, but I'm facing this problem.
from source.main.create_db import vectordb 
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain import prompts
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain import memory
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os as os
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableParallel, RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_anthropic import ChatAnthropic
from langchain_core.documents import Document


load_dotenv()
key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
llm = OpenAI()
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever()

template = '''
ou are an assistant specialized in Brazilian public exams, 
mainly focused on tests in the field of law,
and must answer the questions below
{question}
'''

prompt= ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
output_parser = StrOutputParser()
model = llm

chain1 = prompt | model | output_parser 


template2 = '''
Correct and enhance the {answer} using your new information from the 
{context} and provide more references and support for the newly crafted response."
'''

prompt2 =  ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template2)
setup_and_retrieval = RunnableParallel(
    {'context':retriever , "answer":RunnablePassthrough()}
)

chain2 = ({'answer': chain1} | setup_and_retrieval | prompt2 | model | StrOutputParser() )


a = chain2.invoke('tell me one law')

print(a)


**And that's the error I receive: **
a = chain2.invoke('tell me one law')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 2499, in invoke
    input = step.invoke(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 3144, in invoke
    output = {key: future.result() for key, future in zip(steps, futures)}
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 3144, in <dictcomp>
    output = {key: future.result() for key, future in zip(steps, futures)}
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/retrievers.py", line 141, in invoke
    return self.get_relevant_documents(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/retrievers.py", line 245, in get_relevant_documents
    raise e
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/retrievers.py", line 238, in get_relevant_documents
    result = self._get_relevant_documents(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/vectorstores.py", line 696, in _get_relevant_documents
    docs = self.vectorstore.similarity_search(query, **self.search_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 348, in similarity_search
    docs_and_scores = self.similarity_search_with_score(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 437, in similarity_search_with_score
    query_embedding = self._embedding_function.embed_query(query)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_openai/embeddings/base.py", line 546, in embed_query
    return self.embed_documents([text])[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_openai/embeddings/base.py", line 517, in embed_documents
    return self._get_len_safe_embeddings(texts, engine=engine)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_openai/embeddings/base.py", line 310, in _get_len_safe_embeddings
    token = encoding.encode(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/erickrochaleaodasilva/projeto_de_lei/maquina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tiktoken/core.py", line 116, in encode
    if match := _special_token_regex(disallowed_special).search(text):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or buffer


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

can you pinpoint where exactly the problem is in your code?

@MubashirAhmedSiddiqui, I believe the problem is in the chain2 when parsing the context, I think somehow it doesn't get converted to 'str'
